# Assign JSON Response to Model SwiftUI

Tags: ios, mvvm, swiftui, alamofire

I have successfully parsed JSON by creating a Model. But now I want a View Model which talks to View and the View updates whenever the Model Updates. But I m having hard time initialising the model.

My simplified model looks like this.

`PeopleListM.swift`

```
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire

struct PeopleListM: Decodable {
var all: [Person]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case all = "people"
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    
    let name: String
    let email: String
    let favorite: Bool
    let lastSent: String?

    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case email = "email_id"
        case favorite
        case lastSent = "last_sent"
    }
}


init() {
    let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["disableauth" : "true", "Content-Type": "application/json"]
      AF.request("MY URL", parameters: nil, headers: headers)
        .validate()
        .responseDecodable(of: PeopleListM.self) { (response) in
            guard let result = response.value else { return }
            self.all = result.all
        }
}
```

This code gives me error `Escaping closure captures mutating 'self' parameter`
I tried changing line `self.all = result.all` with `self = result`, same error.

My further plan is create a class which conforms to `ObservableObject`

`PeopleListVM.swift`

```
import SwiftUI

class PeopleListVM: ObservableObject {

 let people = PeopleListVM.createModel()

 static func createModel() {
    PeopleListM()
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
final class PeopleListVM: ObservableObject {

    @Published var people = PeopleListVM.createModel()

    static func createModel() {
        PeopleListM()
    }
    
    func request() {
        // networking here...
        // update people in callback
        // ... self.people = newPeople
    }
}

struct Model: View {
    @ObservableObject var vm = PeopleListVM()   
    // ...
}
```

You generally won't put networking code in `struct`, because networking always comes with state changes, when value type is meant to be immutable.

Comment: But how do I assign the people which is coming from the API to the people in the Model?

Comment: `responseDecodable(of: PeopleListM.self)` decodes to a `PeopleListM`, assign it to `self.people`. this AF.request code should take place in PeopleListVM which is a reference type, so you don't have `mutating self` problem.